# Run .bat as administrator without manual confirmation

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, windows-11

I want my .bat file to always run as administrator without me having to manually allow it to make changes to my device each time. It's part of a larger automated process and simply clears and resets the clipboard. Since it's automated I can't be there each time to hit yes.

```
wmic service where "name like '%%cbdhsvc_%%'" call stopservice
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"
wmic service where "name like '%%cbdhsvc_%%'" call startservice
```

Alternatively is there a way I could set it to run say every 5 seconds in the background with only a single confirmation until I tell it to stop or for a set period? Thanks

Comment: Not possible, Windows specifically disallows running as admin without explicit confirmation from a user. It's part of their protection against malware.

Comment: If you want it to run on a schedule, (every _n_), then create a task in Windows Task Scheduler to run the script with sufficient privileges to not require confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

For only having to allow administrator once, you could use the timeout command.

```
:top
"code"
timeout /t 5 /NOBREAK > nul
goto :top
```

do timeout/? in cmd to see the usage.